# How to call two different controllers from the same form action?

Tags: forms, jsp

I have a signup form in jsp in which i autogenerate the "userid" by getting the maximum value of userid from database in a variable "count" and incrementing it by 1 and display it in input value of form using struts bean:write tag. 
So far so good, now i want the values in signup form to get saved in the database. For that, i need to call a controller2 from form action, but i have already used form action to call the controller1 needed for displaying userid.
How can i call two different controllers from the same form?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have the first controller forward to the second one. Or better yet, just have two functions in one controller and call them both.